# C backtracking generating numbers of 123456789 (1 to 9 digits, all different)

Tags: c, numbers, backtracking, digits

I'd like to generate all numbers like these:

- **1 digit:** 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 -  (I know there are 9 numbers of 1
  digit)
- **2 digits:** 12,13..19 then 21,23...29 .......91,92,93,...98 (I know
  there are 9*8=72 numbers of 2 digits)...
- ...
- **9 digits:** 123456789....987654321 (I know there are 9! numbers of 9
  digits) all the digits are different from each other

I don't think it's a great idea to write all the loops by hand. So I know for a fact that you most probably have to use backtracking method, but I haven't used it for a while.

Comment: What happened with `10` and `20`?

Comment: i intended to create numbers that contain all digits except 0

Comment: i tried this, but i only get 9, 98,987.....987654321 :(
#include <stdio.h>
int numar=0;
void back(int value)
{
    numar=numar*10+value;
    printf("numar=%d",numar);
    if (value>1 ) back(value-1);
    numar=numar/10;
    back(value-1);
}

int main()
{
back(9);
}
yes, i

Comment: @meiznub Let me rephrase: so your question is, how to get all the number permutation for a given number of digits? the input is number of digit (say, 1) and the result is set of permutation (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9). Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

You want to generate all [*k*-permutations of *n*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n) with *n = 9*. The question [Partial permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866921/partial-permutations) has several helpful answers for C++. I ported one implementation to C and adapted it to your need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void comb(char *rest, int n)
{
    static int sofar;
    static char sogood[10];
    if (n == 0)
        puts(sogood);
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(rest); i++)
        {
            sogood[sofar] = rest[i];
            char substring[10];
            strcpy(memcpy(substring, rest, i)+i, rest+i+1);
            ++sofar, comb(substring, n-1), --sofar;
        }
}

int main()
{
    for (int k = 1; k <= 9; ++k)
        comb("123456789", k);
}
```