# Partial permutations

Tags: c++, permutation

I have the following recursive function for outputting partial combinations:

```
void comb(string sofar, string rest, int n) {

    string substring;

    if (n == 0)
        cout << sofar << endl;
    else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rest.length(); i++) {
            substring = rest.substr(i + 1, rest.length());
            comb(sofar + rest[i], substring, n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

called like so:

```
comb("", "abcde", 3);
```

By partial combinations, I mean that it uses n choices and r elements (rather than n choices, n elements).

However, I would like to take the order of elements into account (i.e. permutations). I can find many algorithms for full permutations, but not partial.

Comment: Have you looked at [next_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)?

Comment: @AndyG Thanks for your response. I have, but it seems as though next_permutation can only be used for full permutations (n choices, n elements) rather than partial (n choices, r elements).

Comment: I see. My apologies. I think I understand now. Can you elaborate what you mean by "take the order of elements into account"?

Comment: @TonyD Thank you for the suggestion. Swapping out the substring line seems to create 25 permutations for 5 options, 3 elements, when I believe there should be 60.

Comment: @AndyG With the current code, I will only generate one line to represent the "abc" combination. However, I would like it to generate this combination in all orders possible, for example : "abc", "bac", "bca", etc.

Comment: Ah, so a permutation for each element from an n choose k. Like this? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44f9407944786a9b

Edit: 5 choose 3 is 10 combinations of size 3. Each combination has 3! = 6 permutations, for a total of 60 combinations, as is shown in the linked demo.

Comment: @AndyG That's exactly it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want permutations, so you should capture characters *before AND* after `i` in `substring`:

```
substring = rest.substr(0, i) + rest.substr(i + 1, rest.length());
```

Complete program on <kbd>[coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccbaca3f97f77885)</kbd>:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;

void comb(string sofar, string rest, int n)
{
    // std::cout << "comb('" << sofar << "', '" << rest << "', " << n << ")\n";
    string substring;

    if (n == 0)
        cout << sofar << '\n';
    else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rest.length(); i++) {
            substring = rest.substr(0, i) + rest.substr(i + 1, rest.length());
            comb(sofar + rest[i], substring, n - 1);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    comb("", "abcde", 3);
}
```

Outputs (reformatted):

```
abc abd abe acb acd ace adb adc ade aeb aec aed
bac bad bae bca bcd bce bda bdc bde bea bec bed
cab cad cae cba cbd cbe cda cdb cde cea ceb ced
dab dac dae dba dbc dbe dca dcb dce dea deb dec
eab eac ead eba ebc ebd eca ecb ecd eda edb edc
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This works perfectly and required far fewer changes than I expected!

Comment: @RooAddict: you're welcome.  You were pretty close!  Cheers.

Answer (score 14):

It's time for a performance reality check here.  If you are only interested in visiting the permutation of 5 things 3 at a time, stop reading now, as the number of visitations is so small that it doesn't matter much (unless perhaps you are doing this a billion times).

But if you need to visit more things, and more things at a time, performance can really start to matter.  For example what about visiting the string of 26:  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", six items at a time?  With permutations, costs grow very quickly...

For performance testing it is best to comment out the output to the terminal as that tends to be a very slow operation which swamps everything else.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34867494/576911) (the currently accepted one) looks like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;

void comb(string sofar, string rest, int n)
{
    // std::cout << "comb('" << sofar << "', '" << rest << "', " << n << ")\n";
    string substring;

    if (n == 0)
        ; //cout << sofar << '\n';
    else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rest.length(); i++) {
            substring = rest.substr(0, i) + rest.substr(i + 1, rest.length());
            comb(sofar + rest[i], substring, n - 1);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string s("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    auto t0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    comb("",s, 6);
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration<double>{t1-t0}.count() << '\n';
}
```

On my system (`clang++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -O3`) this outputs:

```
14.2002
```

[This answer using `std::next_permutation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34868103/576911) is significantly faster.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

// Requires: sequence from begin to end is sorted
//           middle is between begin and end
template<typename Bidi, typename Functor>
void for_each_permuted_combination(Bidi begin,
                                   Bidi middle,
                                   Bidi end,
                                   Functor func) {
  do {
    func(begin, middle);
    std::reverse(middle, end);
  } while (std::next_permutation(begin, end));
}

int
main()
{
    std::string s("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    auto t0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for_each_permuted_combination(s.begin(), s.begin()+6, s.end(),
        [](auto first, auto last)
        {
//             for (; first != last; ++first)
//                 std::cout << *first;
//             std::cout << '\n';
        });
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration<double>{t1-t0}.count() << '\n';
}
```

which outputs:

```
8.39237
```

This is 69% faster!  A lot of this speed increase can be attributed to the lack of allocation and deallocation that is implicit in the first algorithm.

However I would like to point you to [an even faster algorithm](http://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html).

The driver looks like:

```
#include "combinations"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    std::string s("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    auto t0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for_each_permutation(s.begin(), s.begin()+6, s.end(),
        [](auto first, auto last)
        {
//             for (; first != last; ++first)
//                 std::cout << *first;
//             std::cout << '\n';
            return false;
        });
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration<double>{t1-t0}.count() << '\n';
}
```

The output is:

```
0.2742
```

This is **30 times faster** than [the answer using `std::next_permutation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34868103/576911) and **51 times faster** than [the currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34867494/576911)!  And as `n` and `r` grow, the divergence of these performance numbers grows as well.

The [linked library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html) is free and open source.  The implementation is at the link and can be copy/pasted out of it.  I won't claim that it is simple.  I only claim that its performance is compelling.  The difference in performance is so dramatic that it can make the difference between making the problem solvable in a practical amount of time or not.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer. I did run across performance problems, so I'll work on implementing the fastest algorithm you mentioned into my code. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Howard, the 69% answer behaves pretty strangely: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/955b4f647e819963 It does not appear to be outputting permutations.

Comment: Additionally, for the same input as OP has, it only produces 20 combinations/permutations when it needs to produce 60. It's no surprise that it's faster than the accepted answer, which produces 3x more.

Comment: I've got to be doing something wrong here, because the second answer (51 times faster answer) also appears to behave strangely, only producing 3 permutations for input of size 3, when in fact 3! = 6. : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f0f7596762e5d45

Comment: @AndyG:  `s.begin()+1` asks for the permutation to chose 1 at a time.  If you want to permute 3 things 3 at a time, specify `s.begin()+3`.  In general, for a string of length `n` to be permuted `r` at a time: `s.begin()+r`.

Comment: Thank you! The `"middle"` argument name was confusing me.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the standard library:

```
// Requires: sequence from begin to end is sorted
//           middle is between begin and end
template<typename Bidi, typename Functor>
void for_each_permuted_combination(Bidi begin,
                                   Bidi middle,
                                   Bidi end,
                                   Functor func) {
  do {
    func(begin, middle);
    std::reverse(middle, end);
  } while (std::next_permutation(begin, end));
}
```

This relies on the fact that `next_permutation` generates permutations in lexicographic order. So if the tail of the sequence is sorted, reversing the tail and then asking for the next permutation of the entire sequence moves the head to the next permutation of a subset, and leaves the tail once again sorted for the next iteration.

In case it's not obvious, the functor is called with a pair of iterators representing the range of the permuted combination.

Comment: Exactly what is used in the proposal:
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.353.930&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Code:
https://github.com/qsimulate-open/bagel/blob/master/src/util/combination.hpp